# Fitting WCS coordinate solution using identified stars with astropy

Tags: python, astropy, model-fitting

I've got a stationary all-sky camera and would like to fit the WCS solution (map pixels x,y to alt,az). If I identify a few stars, I can get an initial solution thusly

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
from astropy.modeling.projections import Sky2Pix_ZEA, AffineTransformation2D
from scipy.optimize import minimize    

# Stars of known x,y on chip and alt,az in sky.
star_obs = np.array([('Achernar', 3441.0, 2918.0, 49.947050461141515, 215.1280625253878),
                    ('Achernar', 3576.0, 3018.0, 43.715460044327585, 217.98734214492922),
                    ('Betelgeuse', 2123.0, 971.0, 43.319872170968644, 40.984431336638984),
                    ('Betelgeuse', 2330.0, 956.0, 47.122656796538564, 32.091831385823845),
                    ('Betelgeuse', 2677.0, 949.0, 51.30177229534061, 14.886238412655885),
                    ('Canopus', 2221.0, 2671.0, 55.59320568854928, 141.12216403321605)],
                    dtype=[('star_name', 'S10'), ('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'),
                    ('alt', '<f8'), ('az', '<f8')])    

class sky2pix(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, alt, az):
        projection = Sky2Pix_ZEA()
        self.affine = AffineTransformation2D()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.projx, self.projy = projection(az, alt)

    def __call__(self, x0):
        self.affine.translation.value = x0[0:2]
        self.affine.matrix.value = x0[2:]
        newx, newy = self.affine(self.projx, self.projy)
        residuals = np.sum((newx - self.x)**2 + (newy-self.y)**2)
        return residuals

fun = sky2pix(star_obs['x'], star_obs['y'], star_obs['alt'], star_obs['az'])
x0 = np.array([np.median(star_obs['x']), np.median(star_obs['y']), 1., 0., 0., 1.])
fit_result = minimize(fun, x0)
```

I'd like to make use of astropy's ability to make compound models and just say `proj_aff = Sky2Pix_ZEA + AffineTransformation2D` and then feed that into a astropy.modeling.fitting routine, but I can't tell how to deal with `AffineTransformation2D` returning 2 outputs.

Comment: Have you tried using [astrometry.net](http://astrometry.net)? This doesn't directly answer your question, but it might nevertheless solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. Turns out astrometry.net is not well suited to fisheye lenses, so it can only converge if I give it a small cut-out near the zenith.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, none of the fitters in `astropy.modeling` can deal with more than one output (a limitation that I also ran into), but this was not clear from the documentation. Moreover, the models `Sky2Pix_ZEA` and `AffineTransformation2D` currently have the attribute `fittable=False`, for some reason.

I have now opened an [issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/6026) for supporting multiple outputs and [documented the limitation](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/fitting.html) in the meantime, but I'm not sure how soon someone will be able to work on this (almost certainly not in time for the upcoming v2.0 release).

Note that it is possible to write your own fitters by sub-classing `Fitter`, as mentioned [here](https://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/modeling/fitting.html#plugin-fitters), if that's of interest. A colleague has written a couple of specialized ones in only tens of lines, though there are a few layers of interfacing with a statistic function and optimizer to understand (from the existing code).